# Часть буфера обмена обрезается при вставке в консольное приложение

Tags: c#

Вставка в произвольный текстовый файл вставляет буфер целиком (примерно 2000 символов) в консольное приложение c# пролезает всего около сотни почему-то. Можно ли как-то увеличить этот объем?

Comment: А вам не кажется, что вставлять в консоль такой объем текста это не есть хорошо, выводить - может быть, но не вставлять. Да и вообще данный вопрос как по мне относится больше к операционной системе, к ее настойке.

Comment: Мне много чего кажется, но так как кажется мне, не работает. ;)

Answer (score 2):

таки нашел как задать длину буфера

```
byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[4096];
Stream inputStream = Console.OpenStandardInput(inputBuffer.Length);
Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(inputStream, Console.InputEncoding, false, inputBuffer.Length));
```